# Concatenação em Python

Tags: python

Estou com dificuldades em concatenar o resultado de uma string com uma string.

```
velas[0] = '\033[0;32;42m   g   ' if velas[0]['open'] < velas[0]['close'] else '\033[0;31;41m   r   ' if velas[0]['open'] > velas[0]['close'] else '\033[0;37;47m   d     ' 
        velas[1] = '\033[0;32;42m   g   ' if velas[1]['open'] < velas[1]['close'] else '\033[0;31;41m   r   ' if velas[1]['open'] > velas[1]['close'] else '\033[0;37;47m   d     '
        velas[2] = '\033[0;32;42m   g   ' if velas[2]['open'] < velas[2]['close'] else '\033[0;31;41m   r   ' if velas[2]['open'] > velas[2]['close'] else '\033[0;37;47m   d     '
        
        cores = velas[0] + ' ' + velas[1] + ' ' + velas[2]  
        
        print(cores)
```

Quando concateno com '+' ele traz a linha pintada conforme o resultado de `'\033[0;32;42m   g   '`, mas não separa com espaço em branco (traz tudo grudado).
Se concateno com ',' `cores = velas[0],velas[1],velas[2]` ele traz a string `'\033[0;32;42m   g   '` separada por espaço.

Eu preciso que o resultado de `'\033[0;32;42m   g   '` seja printado e separado por um espaço em branco.
Alguem consegue ajudar, desculpa, não sei se me fiz entender.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método [string.join()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp)

A sintaxe do comando é:

```
resultado = str_do_caractere_separador.join(lista)
```

Segue um exemplo:

```
cores = ' '.join(velas)
```

Comment: Tentei o comando conforme sugeriu e ainda nao rolou, continua trazendo tudo junto.

Comment: Eu não consigo reproduzir exatamente o código da sua pergunta. Você conseguiria me explicar melhor o funcionamento desse trecho: `if velas[0]['open'] < velas[0]['close'] else '\033[0;31;41m   r   ' if velas[0]['open'] > velas[0]['close'] else '\033[0;37;47m   d     '`